# desplegar datos de un objeto en un option select laravel vuejs

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel-5, vue.js

hola estoy trayendo un array con objetos, los recupero bien, pero no puedo mostrarlos en un select, realizo la consulta con axios en vuejs.
tengo dos llamados get, uno me funciona el cual me muesta el producto, pero al tratar de mostrar marcas en un div no lo logro y no se por que, alguna sugerencia o en lo que me estoy equivocando? gracias

registro.vuejs:

```js
<script>

    export default {
      mounted() {
            console.log( 'el id es: '+ App.user.id);  
        },
      //data con lo que contendra lo que se espera
        data(){
          
          //lo que retorno, defino editmode, creo un objeto vacio y creo el form con los parametros vacios
            return{
                marcas:{},
                productos : {},
                    form: new Form({
                      
                    user_id: App.user.id,
                    id:'',
                    nombre:'',
                    descripcion:'',
                    foto:'',
                    codigo_interno:'',
                    codigo_OEM:'',
                    codigo_proveedor: '',
                    marca_id: '',
                    modelo:'',
                    year: '',
                    categoria_id:''
                    
                })
            }
        },
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        //metodos 
        methods:{
----------------------------*/
            //cargo 
            cargarProducto() {
              
            axios.get("api/producto").then(({ data }) => (this.productos = data.data));       

        } ,
        cargarNesesarias(){
               axios.get("api/marca").then(({ data }) => (this.marcas = data.data));      
            }    
        },

        created(){
          this.cargarNesesarias();
                this.cargarProducto();
                Fire.$on('AfterCreate',()=>{
                  this.cargarProducto();
                  
                })
               // setInterval(()=>this.cargarOferta(),3000);

             
            }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<div v-for="producto in productos" :key = "producto.id">

  {{ producto.nombre }}


</div>

<div v-for="marca in marcas" :key = "marca.id">

  {{ marca.nombre }}


</div>
</template>
```

mi controlador:

```js
public function findMarcas(){
        $marcas  = marca::select("id","nombre","codigo")->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        //$marca = marca::all();
        return response()->json($marcas);
       
    }
```

mi ruta:

```js
Route::apiResources(['producto' => 'API\ProductoController']);
Route::get('marca', 'API\ProductoController@findMarcas');
```

Resultado del get:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la imagen me muestra el array con los objetos, pero no logro obtenerlos en realidad iterarlos y mostrarlos, aunque con el objeto de productos no tengo problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo debe acceder al valor de data, directamente ,`(this.marcas = data)`  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Si estas recibiendo los datos el error esta en la plantilla Vue Js. Lo que yo veo es que el código de Vue Js cada componente necesita tener un elemento padre que encierre todo lo que tu coloques dentro de la etiqueta TEMPLATE.

Ejemplo:

Tu tienes:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="producto in productos" :key = "producto.id">
    {{ producto.nombre }}
  </div>

  <div v-for="marca in marcas" :key = "marca.id">
    {{ marca.nombre }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Pero deberías encerrar los dos divs que hay dentro de la etiqueta TEMPLATE que quede asi:

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-for="producto in productos" :key = "producto.id">
      {{ producto.nombre }}
      </div>

    <div v-for="marca in marcas" :key = "marca.id">
      {{ marca.nombre }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Una recomendación es que tienes las variables marca y producto declaradas como objeto y estas recibiendo un Array, debería declarar `marca: [],  producto: []`.
Es solo recomendación en realidad esto no afecta nada el funcionamiento del programa.